# Сравнить два объекта Date без учёта времени

Tags: ios, swift, дата, datetime

Есть `now = Date()` и есть еще один объект (`someDate`) этого же класса, (который может быть в настоящем/прошлом/будущем).

Какой самый простой способ сравнить два объекта класса `Date` без учёта времени, чтобы понять меньше ли "календарно" `someDate`, чем `now`?

Навскидку получается что-то вот такое:

```
extension Date {

    func isBefore(_ date: Date = Date()) -> Bool {

        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
        let selfDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)

        // сравниваем года

        if selfDateComponents.year! < dateComponents.year! {
            return true
        }

        if selfDateComponents.year! > dateComponents.year! {
            return false
        }

        // сравниваем месяцы

        if selfDateComponents.month! < dateComponents.month! {
            return true
        }

        if selfDateComponents.month! > dateComponents.month! {
            return false
        }

        // сравниваем дни

        if selfDateComponents.day! < dateComponents.day! {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

}
```

но мне кажется есть способ проще/короче/элегантнее )

Comment: Куда уж короче )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения даты без времени используйте `DateComponents`:

```
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: yourDate)
let dateWithoutTime = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents) // дата без времени
```

для удобства можно оформить в `extension` для `Date`:

```
var ignoringTime: Date? {
    let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: self)
    return Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
}
```

Используете:

```
yourDate1.ignoringTime
```

Ну а сравнить уже не проблема.

Либо стандартно:

```
Calendar.current.compare(date1, to: date2, toGranularity: .day)

результат сравнения:
.orderSame - одинаковые
.orderDescending - date1 > date2
.orderAscending - date1 < date2
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так

```
extension Date {

    func isBefore(_ date: Date = Date()) -> Bool {

        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
        let selfComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)

        return calendar.date(from: selfComponents)! < calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
    }
}
```

Просто из компонентов создаем дату обратно `calendar.date(from: dateComponents)` и параметр который не указан в `[.year, .month, .day]`  в сравнении учитыватся не будет (так как выставит дефолтный)

Пример: дата `Sep 4, 2018 at 12:29 PM` будет преобразована в `Sep 4, 2018 at 12:00 AM`